# How can create a metabox wordpress for specific category?

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a meta box that use in specific category like "download" that when i edit a single post from this category showing this meta box and when edit a single post from another category don't show this meta box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly it is not possible to add metabox for a specific category. but you are able to add metabox for specific post type. and then using css you are able to hide for a specific category. you are able to add class for specific category and then using that class you are able to show/hide metabox. using admin_body_class filter you are able to add class.

```
add_filter( 'admin_body_class', 'add_body_classes' );
function add_body_classes( $classes ) {

    if (get_current_screen()->post_type == 'post') {

      global $post;

      foreach((get_the_category($post->ID)) as $category) {

        if($category->name == 'download')
        {           
                $classes .= 'download';
        }

      }
    }       
    return $classes;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Ok . thanks a lot. so i can't add meta box to specific category ... but i can use condition to show class for category that i want. and use css like display:none...
Thanks Nidhi

Comment: @vahab Welcome.  If this answer help you then you are able to give it green tick.